# Scale PDF down from A3 to A4 in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, pdf, scale, pdfsharp

I am trying to change the pdf size from A3 (or whatever) to A4 using Powershell and PDFsharp.
In this example 'test.pdf' is an A3 drawing and 'test2.pdf' would be the output, exactly the same as 'test.pdf' just scaled down to fit on an A4 size paper.
I have managed to change the page size, however it is just cutting off half the document not scaling it down.

```
Import-Module "C:\ProgramData\coolOrange\powerJobs\Modules\PdfSharp.dll"

$PdfReader = [PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfReader]            
$PdfDocumentOpenMode = [PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfDocumentOpenMode] 
$AA = $PdfReader::Open("C:\temp2\test.pdf",$PdfDocumentOpenMode::Modify)
$Array = $AA.Pages
foreach($page in $Array)
{
    $page.Height = 595   
    $page.Width = 842
}

$AA.Save("C:\temp2\test2.pdf")
$AA.Close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new page, then use `DrawImage` to draw the existing page onto the new page and scale it down as needed. With `DrawImage` you specify the destination rectangle.

See this sample:
http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/TwoPagesOnOne-sample.ashx

The sample is C# and shows drawing two portrait pages on one landscape pages, so it is not exactly what you need. But it shows the technique and the methods you need.